# LiteCoreDomain Error while opening a database Couchbase-lite

Tags: electron, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am getting an exception while opening a database in couchbase-lite.I tried using different database name and also checked for the error and referred to [this link](http://docs.couchbase.com/mobile/2.0/couchbase-lite-net/html/T_Couchbase_Lite_CouchbaseLiteError.htm) but it seems that the error is related to the databse file format, but unable to resolve it. Here is the description for the same:

Code snippet:

```
      const config = new DatabaseConfiguration();
      config.setEncryptionKey('secret');
      const database = new Database("test1", config)
      database.setEngine(new CordovaEngine({
        allResultsChunkSize: 128
      }));
      this.database = database;
      this.database.open();
```

Exception message:

> CouchbaseLiteException (LiteCoreDomain / 21): file/data is not in the
>   requested format.

Error Screenshot:
[image]

Can anyone one please help to resolve the issue?

------Edit:
As per suggestion I have removed encryption and tried the db-open and other things,which are working seamlessly now. But nothing works if I add encryption again,how to achieve the same with encryption any idea?

Comment: Is this in an electron app?

Comment: Yes, it is an electron app.

Comment: Does the same thing happen without encryption?

Comment: Yes. Still getting same error without any encryption.

Comment: Did you change the database name before trying just now?

Comment: No, but after changing the database name error is solved thank you.

Comment: It sounds like the old one got corrupted somehow.  This happens in my testing sometimes when a test crashes halfway through and leaves a partially deleted database file or something like that.  You should directly examine the old one to see what it is.  You can also use the static `Database.Delete` method to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks @borrrden, proceeding with Database.Delete method after checking the existence of db.

Comment: @borrrden How to achieve the same with encryption,because now this one works only without encryption any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple options what worked for me is as below:

1. I had to delete the **existing** **Db file** manually, because the file was corrupted.
2. Also used Database.Delete method after checking the existence of db
3. Created new Db with encryption.